# An upgrade from 'eoan' to 'disco' is not supported with this tool

Tags: upgrade, update-manager, 19.10

I was using Ubuntu 19.04 and decided to upgrade it to 19.10. I just used the Software Update Tool.

I did not see any errors during the installation. After rebooting I realized that Ubuntu was not upgraded.

I checked software update tool and got an error message:

> Not all updates can be installed

After I clicked <kbd>Partial Upgrade</kbd> I got another error:

> **An upgrade from 'eoan' to 'disco' is not supported with this tool.**

So how do I finish the upgrade?

Comment: I did a number of disco to eoan upgrades (mostly pre-release QA-tests) and some could churn away  then detect issues, report on them in messages, then back out the change  (I've also seen **many** reports on launchpad of users finding the same, the problems nearly always 3rd party software conflicts). It's possible you had this issue, thus you're still on 19.04 & the upgrade was reverted.  I'd verify what actually happened (look at your sources, are they disco or eoan?, apt logs to see what happened etc..)  To me it's not clear your 'upgrade' actually took place.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if it will work, but try `sudo do-release-upgrade` from terminal. It worked for me.